# Telerik report is not available in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, visual-studio-2017

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 after which I reinstalled Telerik Report and Telerik asp.net web components in my PC, Telerik asp.net web components work well but Telerik report templates don't, the challenge is the report template does not show up when I click the add new Item (Using webforms). This is what I tried:

- Restarted Visual Studio 2017
- Restarted PC
- Referenced Telerik.Reporting to my project
- Selected all Telerik.Reporting Assembly under .NET Framework components in Choose Toolbox items from Tools menu
- Tried the instructions in this thread

What am I not doing ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you asked Telerik? Their support is pretty good. Their support forums are also good, and you'll get more directed help than you would on a general site like SO.

Comment: I see no information about you using telerik control panel. is the option avadable in the Telerik control Panel? You it be a license issue? But as AvrohomYisroel said: Telerik tiket is the best way to solve installating and licensing issue.